# Deterministically generating secure passwords using a publicly visible function

Tags: matlab, cryptography

I would like to avoid storing a list of my passwords, but instead reliably regenerate them using a publicly visible MATLAB function.  This function takes a secret key, which is not stored anywhere, to set the seed of a random number generator.

Is this a secure approach to regenerate my account passwords as I need them? By secure I mean, is it more vulnerable than somebody knowing what my secret key is?

```
% Start with a blank slate
clear all
clc

% {url, #symbols, #upper, #lower, #numbers}
accounts = { ...
    'www.foo.com', [3,3,3,3]; ...
    'www.bar.com', [0,4,4,4]; ...
    'www.box.com', [0,2,3,2]; ...
    };
key = input('Secret Key: ', 's');
acc = input('Account Name (URL): ', 's');
% Clear display immediately
clc

% Allowed characters
s = { ...
    '@#$%&*=+'; ...                 % symbols
    'ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'; ...  % upper
    'abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz'; ...  % lower
'123456789' };                  % numbers

% Find matching accounts
idx = strfind(accounts(:,1), acc);

% Generate password for each matching account
for j = 1:length(idx)
    if isempty(idx{j})
        % Skip if there is no matching account
        continue
    end

    % Salted random number generator seed
    rng(sum([key, ': ', accounts{j,1}]), 'twister');

    ns = accounts{j,2};
    n = sum(ns);

    % Construct password
    p = '';
    for k = 1:length(s)
        v = s{k};
        p = [p v(randi(length(v),1,ns(k)))];
    end
    p = p(randperm(n));
    fprintf('Password for %s is %s\n', accounts{j,1}, p)
end

% Clear all variables for safety
clear all
```

For example, my prototype above results in

```
Password for www.foo.com is q*PZry4@8%3F
Password for www.bar.com is 8nZ8NWa6C8am
Password for www.box.com is wUw3Bn9
```

every time I run my MATLAB code with the input:

```
Secret Key: MySecretKey
Account Name (URL): www
```

Comment: This looks OK, so long as you never will forget your key just encrypt your MATLAB code! Try encrypting your p-code, it is common I hear.

Comment: FYI:  (1) Run your code.  (2)  Use "MySecretKey" and "www.foo.com" as inputs.  (3)  up-arrow twice to see the string "MySecretKey" in your command history.

Comment: Perhaps replacing `input` with `inputdlg` would help with the issue raised by @Pursuit (there's also a `login` dialog on MATLAB Central that replaces typed characters with asterisks), and display results with `msgbox`, as the command line output is captured by `diary`. You should probably also make this a function rather than a script, so you can get rid of the `clear all`s and not worry about clashing variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice program, The weakest point is probably not the algorithm, but the way you use it.

Obviously it is not very secure to type/print passwords in the matlab command window. Log files are kept and could somehow be scraped for your password. Also the fact that the password is visible at some time is a relevant weakness if you use it outside your own home.

The secret key can probably remain invisible with something like this [passwordentrydialog](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19729-passwordentrydialog/content/passwordEntryDialog.m). But if you actually want to use the generated pass you will need to either observe it visually or put it on the clipboard. Either may not be nice in public areas.

---

From a technical point of view it would be possible that if you put it on the shelf for a few years, Matlab may not be able to generate the same random numbers anymore. However if you always check whether it works in a new version before you uninstall the old one it should be fine.

---

All in all I would say it could make a fine mechanism for home use, but if you can remember a lot of individual passwords that would definately be safer. Also note that there are several free services available who can store your passwords for you (protected by a master password).

Answer (score 0):

Other people have already looked at your problem and have come up with a different solution, something like [Password Safe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/passwordsafe/).  You passwords are securely stored, and the program itself takes care of clearing buffers etc. after use.  Disclosure: I use the program myself.